# Google App Engine Search: snippeted HTML field in search results

Tags: html, google-app-engine

I can return a snippeted `TextField` field in the search results of the (experimental) `Google App Engine Search API`. But how can I return a snippeted `HtmlField` field? I tried this, but the `HTML` tags are not removed in the snippeted result. Also, the dot at the end of a sentence is removed in the snippeted result. I would like to present the snippeted results like the Google search results: without `HTML` tags, with a dot at the end of a sentence. Is it possible? Should I just have patience and wait for future releases? That could take a long time. I use Python.

**Edit:** Now I store a copy of the `HTML` content with the `HTML` tags removed in the index document, so that solves the `HTML` problem. But how can I display the punctuation in the snippeted field in the search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there are some issues with the Search API on the development server. In production, punctuation and snippeted HTML field is shown as expected. Also, I think query results are cached somewhere on the development server.

I guess these problems have to do with the Search API still being experimental.